# C# Prevent Console application build as Windows application from exit?

Tags: c#, console-application, exit, windows

I have a Console application, **build as** Windows application, to run as background process (I call it `App 1`).
When I run other app, I send message to `App 1`, then it process message.
I want prevent `App 1` from exit ultil I press a hotkey.

Can you help me **how to prevent `App 1` from automatic exit**? Thank you very much!

Comment: Create some static variable and check for it before exit.

Comment: combine the two answers (since Console.ReadLine() isn't applicable). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this forum

[Prevent console app from exiting when it reaches the end of the main](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/9268d273-b8da-4a9c-ba5a-ea9462577415/)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is how to register a hot key.

Try this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]

public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, int vk);
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: No, I want ask how to prevent App 1 from automatic exit?

Comment: perhaps program a windows/wcf service? the approach of a headless console app is that it exits when done.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // do something here...

        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        while (answer != "Exit")
        {
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Console.ReadLine is not available to a headless console application.